# How to stop/resume a loop without having to terminate the terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a small macro for a game.

I would like to stop the program (NOT close it!) with the F9 key and then when I click F9 again, it will resume. If possible without having to exit the game.

F9 - Start/Stop the program

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

print("Press F10 to stop and F9 to start")

while keyboard.is_pressed('f10') == False:

    if keyboard.is_pressed('f9') == True:
        time.sleep(3)
        pyautogui.press('w')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('s')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('w')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press('s')
        time.sleep(1)
    
    pyautogui.press('a')
    time.sleep(4)
    pyautogui.press('t')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [pynput](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard) to monitor the keyboard

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.f9: # start and stop the macro
        flags['running'] = not flags['running']
    elif key == Key.f10: # closes the program
        flags['exit'] = True
        return False # stop the listener

def macro(flags):
    keyboard = Controller()
    while not flags['exit']:
        if flags['running']: # your macro here
            sleep(3)
            keyboard.type('w')
            # etc...
            

flags = {'running' : True, 'exit' : False}

macro_thread = Thread(target=macro, args=(flags,))
macro_thread.start()

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
    
macro_thread.join()
```

if you want the code to stop immediately you need to change the sleeps inside the macro function:

```
from time import time

def check_exit(s, flags):
    """ checks if the exit flag becomes true for s seconds """
    start = time()
    while time() < (start + s):
        if flags['exit']:
            return True
    return False

def macro(flags):
    keyboard = Controller()
    while not flags['exit']:
        if flags['running']:
            if check_exit(3, flags): return
            keyboard.type('w')
            # etc...
```

Comment: What does flags? Because I don't know how I can run the macro only when I press F9. I tested the program as you recommended, and the macro starts right away, and I want it to start executing the macro when I click on F9.

Comment: `flags` it's a dictionary that is used to store the status of the program, if running is `True` then the macro is active, if `exit` is `True` then the program will close.  If you want the program to start without the macro active just change the value of `running` inside the dictionary from `True` to `False`

Comment: and there is any away to instantly kill the process with the F10 key?

Comment: yes, check the new part that i have added to the answer